# Passing a generic class to a java function?

Tags: java, generics

Is it possible to use Generics when passing a class to a java function?

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
public static class DoStuff
{
    public <T extends Class<List>> void doStuffToList(T className)
    {       
        System.out.println(className);
    }

    public void test()
    {
        doStuffToList(List.class);      // compiles
        doStuffToList(ArrayList.class); // compiler error (undesired behaviour)
        doStuffToList(Integer.class);   // compiler error (desired behaviour)
    }       
}
```

Ideally the List.class and ArrayList.class lines would work fine, but the Integer.class line would cause a compile error.  I could use `Class` as my type instead of `T extends Class<List>` but then I won't catch the Integer.class case above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
public <T extends List> void doStuffToList(Class<T> clazz)
```

You are passing a `Class` after all - the parameter should be of type `Class`, and *its* type parameters should be limited.

Actually, `<T extends Class<..>` means `T == Class`, because `Class` is `final`. And then you fix the type parameter of the class to `List` - not any `List`, just `List`. So, if you want your example to work, you'd need:

```
public <T extends Class<? extends List>> void doStuffToList(T clazz)
```

but this is not needed at all.

Comment: @Bozho http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413818/cannot-access-class-methods-via-generics

Answer (score 5):

ArrayList.class is of type Class<ArrayList>, while the parameter should be a Class<List>. These types are not compatible, for the same reason that List<Integer> is not a List<Number>.

You can define the function as follows, and get the expected behavior:

```
public void doStuffToList(Class<? extends List> className)
```