# Cannot access class methods via generics

Tags: java, class, generics, parameter-passing, deserialization

I changed my method to [generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413112/passing-and-using-class-in-a-method-in-java) method. What is happening now is that I was deserializing the class inside the `methodB` and accessing its methods which I can not do anymore.

```
<T> void methodB(Class<T> clazz) {
    T var;
    HashMap<String, T> hash = new HashMap<>();
}

void methodA () {
  methodB(classA.class);
}
```

Initially inside `methodB` with no generics,

```
var = mapper.convertValue(iter.next(), ClassA.class);
var.blah() //works fine
```

After using generics,

```
var = mapper.convertValue(iter.next(), clazz);
var.blah() //cannot resolve the method.
```

How do I access `blah()` method of `classA`?

Comment: You need to show more code. What error did you get exactly?

Comment: Error:() java: cannot find symbol. More code is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27413112/passing-and-using-class-in-a-method-in-java

Comment: What's the type of `var`? What's the definition of that class?

Comment: Added details in the question

Comment: Is it a compile or runtime error? You must post the actual error message and specify where do you get it (if it is in runtime, the stacktrace is useful).

Comment: What would happen if you called `methodB(String.class)`? `String` has no method `blah`.

Comment: @DWilches It is a compiletime error. Running the program gives me `java cannot find symbol`. When I do `var.`, my IDE does not give me an option to chose any methods as it was when I was not using generics. When I anyhow use it, it gives me that error.

Comment: This has nothing to do with serialization.  It is a compiler error you are getting because your type parameter `T` is not restricted to a type having a `blah` method.  You must specify a proper type boundary.

Comment: @Ava What is `convertValue` returning ? How is that returned class declared?

Comment: `var` is of type `T` and I am passing `ClassA.class` to `clazz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Passing a class with type parameter as type parameter for generic method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18471701/passing-a-class-with-type-parameter-as-type-parameter-for-generic-method-in-java). Solved using [TypeToken](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use interfaces instead of generics, if you want to call the same 'blah' function on a variety of classes (A,X,Y,Z) (each of which has the same function signature)..

Your other option (if you cannot modify A, e.t.c) is to use reflection. read more about this in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 0):

The line where you assign to `var` at runtime is absolutely irrelevant. The only thing that matters for compiling a call is the static (compile-time) type of `var`. Since `T` is unbounded (other than by `Object`), it is not known to support any methods, other than those provided by `Object`. Both pieces of code should fail to compile.